# Upload multiple files in array with yii

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I've created a form with field in array following this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

and created a file field in array like this

```
echo $form->fileField($m, "[$i]myfile");
```

But now i've no idea what i'm going to do in controller to save the file paths and filename etc. I am able to save other information but not the upload file. I've tried with this but no luck.

```
$imageUpload = CUploadedFile::getInstance($models[$i],'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, but first ensure your form type is

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'user-form',
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
            ),
        )); ?>


 //Avatar Upload on controller start


        $uploaded_file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'avatar');

        $main_image=null;
        if($uploaded_file and $model->validate())
        {
            $main_image =time()."-".$model->username.".".$uploaded_file->getExtensionName();

            $model->avatar=$uploaded_file;#initialize model attribute with file name

            $model->avatar->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath."/../images/profile-images/".$main_image);//this will upload selected image file


        }
 //Avatar Upload on controller end
```

Answer (score 0):

This method need the browser support HTML5.

In view file:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'ca-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
));
...
echo $form->fileField($m, "myfile[]", array('multiple'=>true));
```

In Controller:

```
$imageUploads = CUploadedFile::getInstances($models,'myfile');
foreach ($imageUploads as $imageUpload) {
    ...// Here you can use $imageUpload->name.
}
```

Notice the 's' of getInstances